# How can I randomly generate a string 5 symbols long in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a newbie so I'm having problems doing this:P

Currently I have tried this:

```
xs1 :: RandomGen g => Int -> g -> [[Char]]
xs1 n = sequence $ replicate n $ randomRs ('!', '~' ::Char)
```

but I can't give this string to my function:

```
fun1 :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [Char] -> [Char]
fun1 a xs1=[if (a!!n==1) then (xs1!!n) else b | n <- [0, 1,2,3,4]]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why can't you? where is the part of the code where you use fun1 and xs1 together?

Comment: `xs1` is not a `String` - it's a function with two arguments  - you did not provide neither

Comment: in fun1, xs1 is a parameter which is a [Char]

Comment: [No such thing as random](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png) :-)

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code? Do you get an error? If so [edit] your question to include it. If not, edit your question with the output you get and explain what you expect instead.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest way for a beginner to use random stuff is `randomIO` or `randomRIO` - here is an example printing 5 random characters (in the range '!' to '~'):

```hs
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random (Random(randomRIO))

randomString :: Int -> IO String
randomString len = replicateM len $ randomRIO ('!', '~')

select :: (Num f, Eq f) => [f] -> String -> String
select =
    zipWith (\f c -> if f == 1 then c else ' ')

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- there will be a warning without the `:: Int`
    s <- select [1 :: Int,0,1,0,1]  <$> randomString 5
    putStrLn s
```

I'm using `randomRIO` here because using just `randomIO` will give you random characters from all over the place most likely all *unprintable* ;)

I don't know what you are trying to do with `fun1` but I'll gone edit if you make it clear

Comment: I'll try to explain what I'm doing with fun1, lets say a is a list [1, 0,1, 0,1], and xs1 is my randomly generated string lets say ['1','2','3','4','5']. fun1 after receiving both these lists prints ['1',' ', 3, ' ', 5]  . I hope that helps

Comment: so it "selects" the entry? it's not clear - do you expect `"1 3 5"` or `"135"`?  the `'` are not paired up right and `''` (without space) is no valid `Char`

Comment: it should be "1 3 5", sorry if it was unclear

Comment: I updated the answer (called it `select` instead of `fn1` though)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I randomly generate a string 5 symbols long ?

Due to the use of `randomRs`, your `xs1` function returns a list of infinitely long strings.

Also, as `xs1` is a function not a list, you cannot really index it thru the `!!` operator.

Please please: paste the full text of the error message in your question, rather than just writing:

“*I can't give this string to my function:*”.

---

In order to generate random strings,  **you need two things:**

1. a generator, typically returned by `mkStdGen` or `mkTFGen`
2. a *monadic action object* with the appropriate return type

Let's try to do that under the *ghci* Haskell interpreter:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> import System.Random
 λ> import Control.Monad.Random
 λ>
```

So let's get a generator first:

```
 λ> 
 λ> seed = 42
 λ> gen1 = mkStdGen seed
 λ>
```

Then let's write the action object:

```
 λ> 
 λ> act5 = sequence $ replicate 5 (getRandomR ('!', '~' ::Char))
 λ>
 λ> :type act5
 act5 :: MonadRandom m => m [Char]
 λ>
```

The action object is essentially a wrapper around a *transition function* that takes a generator and returns some *(output value, new generator)* pair.

Finally, we combine these two things thru the [`runRand :: Rand g a -> g -> (a, g)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Lazy.html#v:runRand) library function, which returns both the value you want and an updated generator:

```
 λ> 
 λ> (str1, gen2) = runRand act5 gen1
 λ> 
 λ> str1
 "D6bK/"
 λ>
```

And we can even get a second pseudo-random string, courtesy of the updated generator:

```
 λ> 
 λ> (str2, gen3) = runRand act5 gen2
 λ> 
 λ> str2
 "|}@5h"
 λ>
```

And so on ... As you can see, it is not really necessary to use the IO monad for this.

### A slight generalization:

Now, say you need 6 such random strings:

```
 λ> 
 λ> act5rep = sequence (replicate 6 act5)
 λ> 
 λ> :type  act5rep
 act5rep :: MonadRandom m => m [[Char]]
 λ> 
 λ> (strs, newGen) = runRand act5rep gen1
 λ> 
 λ> strs
 ["D6bK/","|}@5h","0|qSQ","h4:.1","3+e-}","}eu,I"]
 λ>
```